# How to get and use certificates with curl

Tags: certificate, curl

1. Entering the following command

   ```
   curl -k email@mail.com:password https://www.example.com
   ```

   Returns the following error

   ```
    <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
   <TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
   <H1>301 Moved</H1>
   The document has moved
   <A HREF="http://mail.google.com/mail/">here</A>.
   </BODY></HTML>
   badauth
   ```
2. after downloading the `cacert.crt` file from here

   ```
   http://www.cacert.org/index.php?id=3
   ```

   Then renamed the `cacert.crt` file to `cacert.pem`

   Then tried:

   ```
   curl --cacert /path/to/cacert.pem email@mail.com:password https://www.example.com
   ```

   But get the same error.
3. Then trying:

   ```
   curl  https://www.example.com
   ```

   I get this error

   > curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
   >   More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
   >
   > curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
   >   If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might not match the domain name in the URL).
   >   If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use the -k (or --insecure) option
4. So I tried with `-k`

   ```
   curl  -k https://www.example.com
   ```

   But of course get the error

   > `Badauth`

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the certificate file but I don't know where to get a certificate file or what to do with it once I have it.

I have no problem logging in using a browser of course but I'd like to automate the process with the command line so I can do this with tasker on my Android tablet over WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

SUCCESS!!

I went through a free web service called dnsomatic (run by the folks at opendns)

It's as simple as signing up for an account and adding opendns to your services. No configuration beyond that.

For Android users busybox versions of wget are way behind and don't have options to use user names and passwords, so we will have to install and use cURL

The guide to install curl can be found here

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2362386

Once you have curl you can simply do things like updating your opendns ip

```
curl -u opendnsusername:password http://updates.dnsomatic.com/nic/update?hostname=opendnshostname
```

Comment: I still can't figure out how to get and use certificates with curl but my ultimate goal has been accomplished. Maybe someone can help with the certificate bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the cacert root certificates from here: http://www.cacert.org/index.php?id=3

Comment: Do I just choose the basic pem format .crt file and change it's name to .pem?

Comment: Apparently not. I downloaded the .crt file that says it's in pem format and renamed it to curlcacert.pem and did curl --cacert /path/to/curlcacert.pem https://www.site.com but still get cert errors.

Comment: What do I do with them once I download them? Can't I just use the same cert my browser uses?